# Resistance of a cloud of free electron gas by Kubo formula?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

How much is the resistance of a cloud of free electron gas, if at all?

How much is the resistance of a cloud of free electrons in a periodic potential?

Did anyone calculate it using the Kubo formula?

Answer (score 1):

There is no resistance is this scenario. You need a scattering mechanism like electron-phonon scattering or electron-defect scattering to obtain a non-infinite conductivity.

Comment: even for the periodic potential case? But as far as I remember, Thouless et al. used Kobo formula to calculate the (finite) Hall resistance in the integer quantum Hall effect.

Comment: That is an exceptional case due to chiral edge states. Was your question not in regard to a regular 3D crystalline metal? If it was, then my answer stands.